# ActiveModel: different validation messages per view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I use the same model in two views (containing forms) and I want to provide different validation messages per view. Example:

**View 1:**

```
Please fill in this bla bla
```

**View 2:**

```
Fill in foo foo
```

I followed the i18n guides to override the default error messages for the model but I can't find a way to differentiate them per view.

Is this possible?

Comment: which rails version do you use?

Comment: did you think about customize the methods? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message

Comment: @devanand I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should be using two different view models. Hence, you will have two classes/models with Single Responsibility.

Panayotis

Comment: I was hoping to find a i18n scope oriented solution but probably I'll go this way.